# PHP - uploaded image not displaying properly

Tags: php, image, post, file-upload

I'm uploading a photo to my PHP server using this HTML form:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="photoServer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the PHP server code

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$target_path = "photoServer.php";
$fname = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
$target = $target_path. '/' . $fname;

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);

echo "<p> Here's your image! $fname </p> </br>"; 
echo "<img src=$target >";

?>
```

Here's what happens when I run this PHP code. I get a small thumbnail instead of camera.jpeg

[image: Here's the captured image of the echo HTML result]

and here's the HTML element for that display thumbnail

```
<img src="photoServer.php/camera.jpeg">
```

Anyone have a clue as to what's going on?

Comment: in $target_path you have to assign the path where you are uploading your photo

Comment: This is not a thumbnail, this means that the image cannot be found.

Comment: Well, `photoServer.php` appears to be a PHP file, not a directory. Is that the case? Are the photos actually uploading properly?

Comment: @Jasper that's the name of my script above. I'm running it on https:// localhost/photoServerProject/photoServer.php

Comment: where are you uploading the photos, `photoServer.php` ins't a folder

Comment: @MarkKennedy Well then you are probably getting an error from the `move_uploaded_file` function about the target directory not existing. Create a new directory, give your PHP user permissions to create files in the new directory, then update your PHP code to point to the new directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your code

```
$target = $target_path. '/' . $fname;
// where $target_path is "photoServer.php"
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target);
//$target doesnt exist on server????
```

so your are trying to save to a non existing path in your server. so the `move_uploaded_file` wont be working.

#### updated to comments below

you may give the path pointing to an existing folder in your server. like

```
$target = './images/' . $fname;
```

Comment: What should the path be then?

Comment: @MarkKennedy the path depend of your server... can be somthing like this `/var/www/html/uploaded_files/`, you have to create the folder

Comment: create the folder just the way @Emilio Gort has told. But while pointing the save path in your code, just give the relative url from your executing file. like './uploaded_files/yourfile.jpg'